# Click Event on Relatively Positioned Element's Original Position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<button>` element that I want to have a 3D effect. In order to create the 3D effect, I added a `box-shadow` to the button, and when the button is clicked, the `box-shadow` turns off, and I give it a relative position to give the effect of being pressed down (you can get a better idea from the codepen below).

I also need to use the button's click event to fire some javascript. The problem is, If the user clicks near the top of the button, a click event is never fired, because once the relative position is applied, the spot that the user clicked, which at the time of the click was on the button, is now above the button, and thus no click is registered.

I am really stumped by this, and I cannot find a way to get this to work, so I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Here is a [link to the codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvPLYR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your button's content in a `span`, and manipulate *that* so that the button's actual location doesn't change.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click',function(){
  console.log('The button was clicked');
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

button span {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5em skyblue;
}

button:active span {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.5em;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<button><span>Click Me</span></button>
```